# Query google to get first image result

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I am trying to setup a process where I can query a google API with a text string to get the first image result.

I have setup a [Google Custom Search Engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/) but I can't seem to replicate a standard google search. My settings:

- Image Search: ON
- Domains to include: google.com. Include all sites this page links to

My hope with above settings was that it would imitate a standard google search. But when I try the term "poker", I get no results. I'm assuming this has something to do with my CSE settings but not sure how to adjust.

[image]

Comment: Please post code samples.

Comment: @JohnFeltz there's no code sample. I added an image of the CSE console showing results. Sorry - removed RoR tag

Comment: Sorry - I was confused by the question title.  Suggest you edit it to remove 'Rails' since you're not at that point yet...

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the option to search the entire web:

1. In the left-hand menu, under Control Panel, click Basics.
2. In the Search Preferences section, select Search the entire web but emphasize included sites.

[screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgn6q.png)